# I think I am looking for the ESC char to use in a DOS Batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, char, dos

The code that is confusing me:

```
set CLEAN=\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Directory One\Sub Directory\30% Dalton.txt
IF EXIST %CLEAN% echo "It Works"
```

This code will never work because the file name has a " % " char

Is there a way to get around this and produce the Echo "It Works"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double % sign. A quick Google led me to the answer.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

```
set CLEAN=\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Directory One\Sub Directory\30%% Dalton.txt
IF EXIST %CLEAN% echo "It Works"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set CLEAN=\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Directory One\Sub Directory\30%% Dalton.txt
IF EXIST "%CLEAN%" echo "It Works"
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around `%CLEAN%` because your file/path contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Do

> %%

to escape